# Python imaging, resize Turtle Graphics window

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

My image is too large for the turtle window.  I had to enlarge the image because the text I need at each spot overlaps.

How do I Resize the window in python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you have drawn an image, but it has gone outside the borders of the window, so therefore you need to make the window larger to see the entire image.

To resize the window:

> setup( width = 200, height = 200, startx = None, starty = None)

This will make your output window 200X200 (which may be too small for you so you'll need to make those numbers larger.)

Here is the URL where I found this information.
[TurtleDocs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#module-turtle)

Comment: Is there any way to change the text size in the write() procedure?

Comment: In python 2.6 there appears to be a way to do that.  turtle.write("Hello",move=False,align="right",font=("Arial",24,"normal")).  I can't test this as I have 2.5.2 installed not 2.6.  http://www.python.org/doc/2.6/library/turtle.html
Hope this helps